# Solve the functional inequality $f(x+1)>(f(x))^2-f(x)+1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

Suppose $f(x):[0,\infty)\longrightarrow [0,\infty)$ satisfies
$$f(x+1)>(f(x))^2-f(x)+1$$
for sufficiently large values of $x$.

Can we solve this functional inequality or get some good information about it? We can put some conditions like $f$ is continuous if necessary.

Comment: You may assume that the inequality holds for all $x,$  by replacing $f(x)$ with $f(x+x_0).$

Comment: Do you have any examples ? I have found one: $f(x)=x(x+1)^{-1}.$

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks. Constants coefficients were missing.

Comment: The inequality only relates numbers that differ by an integer, so this reduces to just solving the problem for sequences $\mathbb{N} \to [0,\infty)$ and then choosing a valid sequences for every $x \in [0,1)$. I think @RyszardSzwarc's formulation is as neat a description of that solution as you're going to get though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a family of solutions: $f_{a,b}(x)=a^{b^x}$, where $a>1$ and $b\geq 2$.

Proof: if $x \geq 0$, then
$$
f_{a,b}(x+1)=a^{b^{x+1}}=a^{bb^x}\geq a^{2b^x}=(a^{b^x})^2>(a^{b^x})^2-a^{b^x}+1
=(f_{a,b}(x))^2-f_{a,b}(x)+1.\quad\square
$$

Comment: Your function satisfy much stronger condition $f(x+1)>f(x)^2,$ $f(x)>1.$ I was looking for $f$ with moderate growth. (+)

Answer (score 4):

The inequality can be rewritten as $$f(x+1)-f(x)>[f(x)-1]^2$$
Let $g(x)=f(x)-1.$ Then
$$g(x+1)-g(x)>g(x)^2$$ For $x-y\notin\mathbb{Z}$ there is no relation between the values $f(x+n)$ and $f(y+m)$ if we do not impose the continuity of $f.$

Fix $0\le x<1$ and set $a_n=g(x+n).$ Then
$$a_{n+1}-a_n> a_n^2\quad (*)$$

There are two possible cases
$$\lim_na_n=\infty\quad {\rm or}\quad \lim_na_n=0$$

The first case can be described pretty precisely.

As $\lim a_n=\infty,$ we get $a_{n_0}>1$ for some $n_0.$  Then $a_n=e^{b_n}$ for $b_n>0.$  We obtain
$$e^{b_{n+1}-b_n}>e^{b_n}+1$$
Hence $b_{n+1}>2b_n,$ i.e. $b_n>2^{n-n_0}b_{n_0}.$
Finally $$a_n> e^{2^nc},\quad n\ge n_0,\ c>0\quad (**)$$
On the other hand the sequence $a_n=e^{2^nc}-1$ satisfies the inequality $(*),$ which shows that the estimate in $(**)$ is sharp.

Concerning the case $\lim_na_n=0$ i.e. $f(x+n)<1$ an example follows. For $f(x)=1-{a\over x+b}$ we get $$f(x+1)-f(x)={a\over (x+b)(x+b+1)}\\ [f(x)-1]^2={a^2\over  (x+b)^2}$$ The desired inequality holds for $b>0$ and $0<a<{b\over b+1}.$

**Remark** Assume $f(x)$
satisfies the inequality.  Then $f(x)\neq 1.$ Assume $f$ is continuous.  Then $f(x)<1$ for all $x$ or $f(x)>$ for all $x,$ by the IMV property.